# Fragments inside a Gridview in Android

Tags: android, gridview, fragment

Is it possible to accommodate a Fragments view inside a Gridview.  I m unable to find any support with regards to this in the internet.
My basic requirement is i m unaware how many fragments i would be in need i to display wherein the number of fragments would be decided dynamically. Each fragment would contain a separate webviews inside it. 
Any sample code would be of great help

Answer (score 1):

Fragment doesn't inherited from View. So its impossible to populate grid with fragments. GridView needs in BaseAdapter which should implement View getView method.

You should write your custom views instead of fragments.

Comment: I agree with first sentence, havent tried what you said after, but I have tried programmatically adding a framelayout right after the gridview generates, and adding a fragment to those. You will find yourself in even more trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Fragment is independent from view even also from activity .it has life-cycle .I mean you cant make fragment inside GridView. Either you have to make your own custom view by extending gridview .or Use only fragment. Use add and replace to do more ...if you want to play with fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use GridVew but you have a GridLayout, where fragments can be put